# code not get input expression from textbox in webview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-webview

I couldn't be successful getting the user expression and shown in toast.

For instance, `onPageFinished` function is invoked and finished execution, before I write some mathematical expression in the `textbox`. And hence nothing is showing on `toast`.

I want to get the input in `runtime` and shown in `toast`.

The below code works fine when I hardcoded expression and stored it the string **(final String mathProblem="2+1";)** like this.

But it's not working for runtime expression I entered in the `textbox`. Any help would be appreciated.

**Here is the code to calculate expression:**

```
final WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview1); 
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override 
    public void onPageFinished(final WebView view,final String url)
    {
       super.onPageFinished(view,url); 
       if(_hasAnsweredQuestion) return; 
       _hasAnsweredQuestion=true; 
       EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
       String mathProblem=editText1.getText().toString(); 
       final String newUrl="javascript:AndroidFunction.showToast("+mathProblem+");"
       webView.loadUrl(newUrl); 
    }
});
```

**Here is the code to show the toast**

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() { 
     @SuppressWarnings("unused") 
     @JavascriptInterface 
     public void showToast(final String webMessage) {
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,webMessage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     } 
},"AndroidFunction"); 
webView.loadUrl(" ");
```

Comment: final WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview1);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{@Override
public void onPageFinished(final WebView view,final String url){super.onPageFinished(view,url);
        if(_hasAnsweredQuestion)
          return;
        _hasAnsweredQuestion=true;
        EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String mathProblem=editText1.getText().toString();
        final String newUrl="javascript:AndroidFunction.showToast("+mathProblem+");";
        webView.loadUrl(newUrl); }});

Comment: webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
    { @SuppressWarnings("unused")
 @JavascriptInterface
      public void showToast(final String webMessage)
        {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,webMessage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    },"AndroidFunction");
  webView.loadUrl(" ");
  }

Comment: above are two codes 1st one calculate expression and 2nd one diplsy answer in the toast

Comment: I am not from android background. I have added your code from comments into question. Check is that correct and change if anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think here is the problem "javascript:AndroidFunction.showToast("+mathProblem+");"
you just this line code as follow

```
"javascript:AndroidFunction.showToast('"+mathProblem+"');"
```

it may help. 
Thanks

Comment: when i tried above line in my code, toast display 2+1 instead of 3.

Comment: this is due to you want to add number in string . it is not possible. So before passing it to string  do add functionality.

Comment: see this code..   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747069/is-there-a-mathematical-expression-parsing-library-on-android/16475485#16475485      it works and give answer